# How to modify code to avoid Overflow error when applying random.sample() large integer inputs?

Tags: python, random, input

The program shows "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t" for large integer inputs(which are mandatory to test the efficiency of the program for all the boundary cases).How do I deal with this error?

```
import random
import sys
 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)

t=int(input())

N =[]
K =[]
B =[]
while 1<=t<=20 :
    n,k,b= input().split()
    n,k,b = [int(n), int(k),int(b)]
    t=t-1
    N.append(n)
    K.append(k)
    B.append(b)
if b >= 1 and b <= (10**5) and n >= 1 and k <= (10**18) and b <= k :
   i1=0
   for val in K:
        n=N[i1]
        k=K[i1]
        b=B[i1]
        i1=i1+1
        print('i entered for loop')
        if sum(list(range(1, k+1))) >= n:
            print(' i entered if loop')
            def possibilities():
                     p = random.sample(range(1, k+1), b)
                     if sum(p) == n:
                        for i in range(0,b):
                            print(p[i],end=" ")
                        print("\r")
                     else:
                         possibilities()
             
            possibilities()         
            
                        
        else:
          print(-1)
```

Comment: Use a C integer type that will hold up to 10^18.

Answer (score 0):

as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) works

> over an arbitrarily large range

so instead of doing:

```
    p = random.sample(range(1, k+1), b)
```

you could do the following:

```
    p = [random.randrange(1, k+1) for _ in range(b)]
```

and have it work for arbitrarily large values of `k`.  note that when `k` is smaller than `2**63-1` (assuming you're using a 64bit machine) using `sample` is likely going to be faster.

as an example of where your code was apparently failing, `random.sample(range(2**63), 1)` gives

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

while `[random.randrange(2**63) for _ in range(10)]` gives me a list containing a single large number.

I also note that:

1. the distributions involved in your code would seem to allow you to give a nice analytical answer in `O(t)` time
2. you might also want to improve your checks to stop it running forever, e.g. `n,k,b = [2,2,2]` would seem to pass all your checks but will spin forever
3. using a `for` loop would be much more efficient than recursion given that Python isn't "tail recursive"